# Eclipse is not working after updating Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I upgraded to Java 1.8. Now, when I try to run my project in Eclipse, I get this error.

> Unable to locate executable for jre1.8.0_65

I googled it and found an answer, which I followed. It recommended I re-add the Java VM, but it left out important details: I don't know the name of the jars I'm looking for, so I'm lost. What do I need to do?

I'm running Windows 10 and eclipse-java-mars-1-win32-x86_64.

Comment: @AustinD - I give up editing :D

Comment: Join the dark side https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Go to `Windows > Preferences`.
- Locate `Java > Installed JREs`. (Or simply type `JREs` in the search box).
- The screen will show the list of JREs.
- Click on `Add` button,
- Click `Standard VM`
- Click `Directory...` in the top left corner
- Navigate to the JRE directory... it's likely in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73`
- Click `OK`
- Click `Finish`
- Remove the old JRE from the list if it still is listed
- Tick the checkbox next to `jre1.8.0_73`
- Click `Apply`
- Click `OK`